# Initialize a struct from elements of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct, initialization

I was wondering if it was possible to use a vector as the initializer list for a vector. So, if I have

```
struct somedata{
    string str1;
    string str2;
}

struct moredata{
    string str1;
    string str2;
    string str3;
}

template<class Dataholder>
Dataholder queryUser(args){
    auto vec = get_vector_from_user(args)
    Dataholder dat{vec}; // The elements of vec become the structured variables in dat.
    return dat;
}
```

So, the user might input 2 or 3 strings when `get_vector_from_user()` is called. However, I know that the programmer will always template `queryUser` and that there will be the same number of elements in `vec` as strings in the `Dataholder` template. Is it possible to initialize a struct with the members of a vector? Thanks!

Comment: Write a constructor that accepts vector and initialize members accordingly

Comment: @Slava Well, true but I suppose the OP wanted a built-in language feature for that, similar to a vector initialization from an iterator pair or such.

Comment: This resembles a bit the problems non-reflecting languages like C++ (as opposed to Java or C#) have with automated serialization. There is no built-in way to "enumerate" members of arbitrary classes.

Comment: Also, the way your data classes look lets me suspect that you should use a vector or array in each class; if you do that the language gives you more support to initialize those in a constructor from other containers: Elements in containers *are* enumerable.

Comment: Why is `get_vector_from_user` returning a `std::vector` and not a `std::array`?

Comment: Hi, yes, I could have written a constructor to initialize with the vector. It seems like that's what I'll do. @Peter-ReinstateMonica is correct, I was looking for something less literal than that, sort of how in python you can *arr to destructure its elements.

Comment: The reason for doing this is because a function returns a vector of data in an order that is defined, but accessing them with array indices is a little magic number-y, so using a struct to access them via name is more readable. @TedLyngmo that function is an example, it's actually a lot more complex than the example displays.

Comment: @JacobSteinebronn Ok, but does the number of elements in the returned vector need to be exactly the same as the number of member variables in `Dataholder`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, but I didn't write the query function and I can't change it, it's not mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the class in question, write a constructor which accepts a `std::vector`, or include the logic directly in the function template:

```cpp
struct somedata{
    string str1;
    string str2;
    somedata(const std::vector& vec) : str1(vec[0]), str2(vec[1]){
        
    }
}

struct moredata{
    string str1;
    string str2;
    string str3;
    moredata(const std::vector& vec) : str1(vec[0]), str2(vec[1]), str3(vec[2]){
        
    }
}

template<class Dataholder>
Dataholder queryUser(args){
    auto vec = get_vector_from_user(args)
    Dataholder dat{vec}; // The elements of vec become the structured variables in dat.
    return dat;
}
```

Just make sure you add a check to assert there are correct number of elements in the vector.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. Enumerating structure members requires complex templates, and possibly code generation because you might need boilerplate code for each specific number of structure members. Luckily there's a library that does it. Behold [Boost.PFR](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_pfr.html), aka `magic_get`.

Its interface mimics that of `std::tuple`, so it's easy to use.

The two major limitations are:

- Your structs must be aggregates (i.e. can't have custom constructors, and more)
- There is no way to get member names

You will also need a compile-time `for` loop:

```
template <typename Integer, Integer ...I, typename F>
constexpr void constexpr_for_each(std::integer_sequence<Integer, I...>, F &&func)
{
    (func(std::integral_constant<Integer, I>{}) , ...);
}

template <auto N, typename F>
constexpr void constexpr_for(F &&func)
{
    if constexpr (N > 0)
        constexpr_for_each(std::make_integer_sequence<decltype(N), N>{}, std::forward<F>(func));
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
struct A
{
    std::string x;
    std::string y;
    std::string z;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec = {"a", "b", "c"};
    if (vec.size() != boost::pfr::tuple_size_v<A>)
        throw std::runtime_error("Wrong vector size.");
    A a;
    constexpr_for<boost::pfr::tuple_size_v<A>>([&](auto index)
    {
        constexpr auto i = index.value;
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::string, boost::pfr::tuple_element_t<i, A>>);
        boost::pfr::get<i>(a) = vec[i];
    });

    std::cout << a.x << ' ' << a.y << ' ' << a.z << '\n'; // a b c
}
```

<kbd>[Run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:29,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:29,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:29,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:29),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdexcept%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0A%23include+%3Cboost/pfr.hpp%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+Integer,+Integer+...I,+typename+F%3E%0Aconstexpr+void+constexpr_for_each(std::integer_sequence%3CInteger,+I...%3E,+F+%26%26func)%0A%7B%0A++++(func(std::integral_constant%3CInteger,+I%3E%7B%7D)+,+...)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cauto+N,+typename+F%3E%0Aconstexpr+void+constexpr_for(F+%26%26func)%0A%7B%0A++++if+constexpr+(N+%3E+0)%0A++++++++constexpr_for_each(std::make_integer_sequence%3Cdecltype(N),+N%3E%7B%7D,+std::forward%3CF%3E(func))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct+A%0A%7B%0A++++std::string+x%3B%0A++++std::string+y%3B%0A++++std::string+z%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::vector%3Cstd::string%3E+vec+%3D+%7B%22a%22,+%22b%22,+%22c%22%7D%3B%0A++++if+(vec.size()+!!%3D+boost::pfr::tuple_size_v%3CA%3E)%0A++++++++throw+std::runtime_error(%22Wrong+vector+size.%22)%3B%0A++++A+a%3B%0A++++constexpr_for%3Cboost::pfr::tuple_size_v%3CA%3E%3E(%5B%26%5D(auto+index)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++constexpr+auto+i+%3D+index.value%3B%0A++++++++static_assert(std::is_same_v%3Cstd::string,+boost::pfr::tuple_element_t%3Ci,+A%3E%3E)%3B%0A++++++++boost::pfr::get%3Ci%3E(a)+%3D+vec%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++%7D)%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+a.x+%3C%3C+!%27+!%27+%3C%3C+a.y+%3C%3C+!%27+!%27+%3C%3C+a.z+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.02610966057441,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1200,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:%27176%27)),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+12.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:33.20744878577278,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%232+with+x86-64+clang+12.0.0%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:49.97389033942559,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

Comment: This is super cool! Unfortunately, the point of doing this was so that I could use member names instead of hard-coded array indices, but this is some very useful knowledge moving forward!

Comment: @JacobSteinebronn ... but, that's exactly what this sorcery does, isn't it? The `a` in the example above is the `Dataholder` instance `dat` in your question.

Comment: @JacobSteinebronn I agree with Ted Lyngmo, isn't it exactly what you asked for? You don't need member names here. Unless you wanted to extract the numbers from member names (assuming all of them are named `strN`), and use them as indices, ignoring the actual member order, but that doesn't make too much sense, since you might as well use arrays. The approach in the answer ignores names, and uses the members in the order they are declared. Hardcoding indices is not required.